# Aggregating on groups of data order by date in Snowflake

Tags: aggregate-functions, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I have the following data in my table:
[image]

I need the output to be the following in Snowflake:
[image]

It is basically, order by transaction date and getting the first transaction and the last transaction for the country and city and the count of transactions as they are done in sequence. I tried using window functions but I'm not getting the desired result. The tricky part if you can see is that the grouping has to be done but in sequence. You can see TEXAS and CALIFORNIA repeating depending on the sequence of transactions for the country and city.

Best it can be via a query. Second best, in some other way of computation that is fast. Has to be done on batches of data. I don't really want to go to an approach where the data is pulled in an order and then gone through row by row in a sequence unless that is the only option. Open to advises on that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a logic and the following query works:

```
select countryid, regionid, min(requesttime), max(requesttime), count(*) from (select deviceid,countryid,regionid,cityid, requesttime,
             row_number() over (partition by countryid order by requesttime) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by countryid, regionid order by requesttime) as seqnum_2
      from table t order by requesttime
     ) t group by countryid, regionid, (seqnum_1 - seqnum_2) order by min(requesttime);
```

Answer (score -1):

Hint: GROUP BY, MIN, MAX, COUNT

Comment: This does not give multiple rows for TEXAS and CALIFORNIA